# C language: When [variables++] in array[ ] work? For example, when array[j++] = arr[i]. It is doing j++ first or do = arr[i] first?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, duplicates, post-increment

**disclaimer** this is not my code and this code is from [Remove Duplicate Elements from an Array in C - Javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/remove-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-c)

What I want to know is in the Example 2 coding part. (I edit code a bit for me or you can see the code clearly.)

```
/* program to delete the duplicate elements from sorted array in C. */  
#include <stdio.h>  
  
int duplicate_element ( int arr[], int num)  
{  
    // check num is equal to 0 and num == 1  
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)  
    {        
        return num;  
    }
         
    // create temp array to store same number     
    int temp [num];   
      
    // declare variable  
    int i, j = 0;  
      
    // use for loop to check duplicate element  
    for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)  
    {  
        // check the element of i is not equal to (i + 1) next element  
        if (arr [i] != arr[i + 1])  
        {            
             temp[j++] = arr[i];  
        }
    }
  
    temp[j++] = arr[ num - 1];  
  
    // check the original array's elements with temporary array's elements  
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)  
    {  
        arr[i] = temp[i];  
    }     
          
    return j;     
}  
  
int main ()  
{  
    int num;

    printf (" Define the no. of elements of the array: ");  
    scanf (" %d", &num);  
      
      
    int arr[num], i;  
      
    printf (" Enter the elements: ");  
    // use loop to read elements one by one  
    for ( i = 0; i < num; i++)  
    {  
        scanf (" %d", &arr[i]);  
    }  
      
    printf (" \n Elements before removing duplicates: ");  
    
    for ( i = 0; i < num; i++)  
    {  
        printf (" %d", arr[i]);  
    }  
      
    num = duplicate_element (arr, num);  
      
    // print array after removing duplicates elements  
    printf (" \n Display array's elements after removing duplicates: ");  
    
    for ( i = 0; i < num; i++)  
    {  
        printf (" %d", arr[i]);  
    }     
          
    return 0;     
      
}
```

Here's the question, what does all j++ in function duplicate_element do? (If possible I would like to know what the code is doing since line // use for loop to check duplicate element until before return too. This part I'm just curious if I know it correctly or not.)

This is my understanding (**j is the final size of arr[]**). In the first question, when executed

j right now is 0

temp[j++]

is it plus the value of j by 1 first then assign value arr[i] to temp[1]. (Does this right?)

The second question, in the first for loop checks when the value in arr[i] is not equal to the value in arr[i + 1] then assign value in temp[j++] with value in arr[i] until for loop is over then assign temp[j++] with arr[num - 1]

(j++ right now is dependent on the if condition for example when all value is not equal to the value of j++ == value of num - 1 and num - 1 is equal to the last value of arr)

and in the last for loop, it assigns every value in Array arr with Array temp. (Does this right?)

Comment: Any C tutorial should explain what `j++` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the code is very bad.

Firstly, the function should be declared like

```
size_t duplicate_element ( int arr[], size_t num );
```

That is the size of the passed array should be specified using the unsigned integer type `size_t` instead of the signed `int` type int. Otherwise this declaration of the variable length array

```
// create temp array to store same number     
int temp [num];
```

along with this statement

```
temp[j++] = arr[ num - 1];
```

will invoke undefined behavior if the user will pass as the second argument a negative number and according to the function specification it allows to pass a negative number.

Secondly, using the variable length array `temp`

```
// create temp array to store same number     
int temp [num];
```

makes the function unsafe. It can occur such a way that the program will be unable to define this variable length array.

The approach is too complicated, confusing and inefficient.

As for your question relative to the postfix operator `++` then according to the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
> As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
> is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

So in fact this statement

```
temp[j++] = arr[i];
```

may be equivalently rewritten like

```
temp[j] = arr[i];
j += 1;
```

As the function adds to the array `temp` the last element in a series of duplicated elements in the array `arr` then after this main loop

```
// use for loop to check duplicate element  
for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)  
{  
    // check the element of i is not equal to (i + 1) next element  
    if (arr [i] != arr[i + 1])  
    {            
         temp[j++] = arr[i];  
    }
}
```

you need to add the last element pf the array `arr` to the array `temp`

```
temp[j++] = arr[ num - 1];
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be rewritten and can look more simpler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t duplicate_element( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t m = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || a[i] != a[m-1])
        {
            if (i != m) a[m] = a[i];
            ++m;
        }
    }

    return m;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t m = duplicate_element( a, N );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, the statement

```
temp[j++] = arr[i];
```

is equivalent to

```
int old_value_of_j = j;
j = j + 1;
temp[old_value_of_j] = arr[i];
```

Comment: I would say it is equivalent to `temp[j] = arr[i]; j = j + 1;`

Comment: It could be either -- the order of the side effects (when j is updated and when the array element is modified) is unspecified.  This can give undefined behavior in other cases where the two objects being updated may alias